# Monero Payments for WooCommerce plugin?

Tags: payment-integration

There is at least one plugin that allows WordPress sites running WooCommerce (a very popular and free e-commerce solution) to accept Bitcoin. As far as I know no similar solution exists for Monero. How difficult would it be to develop such a plugin? Is Monero core development at such a stage that developing a Monero Payments plugin is not yet feasible or advisable?

Answer (score 6):

Serhack is developing the woocommerce plugin for wordpress.
Check it: https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerowp

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a plugin put there are a few merchant solutions available. See the "Libraries and Helpers" section on the following page:

https://getmonero.org/getting-started/merchants